# duplicates in a join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, cartesian-product

the following SQL is returning every `BT.Bt_Name` where `L.date_back` is Null. I only wish to select the `BT.Bt_Name`s where `L.Bc_id` is duplicated

```
SELECT BT.Bt_Name
FROM Book_Title BT INNER JOIN (
    Book_Copy BC INNER JOIN Loan L ON BC.Bc_id = L.Bc_id
)   ON BT.Bt_id = BC.Bt_id
WHERE L.Date_back Is NULL
GROUP BY BT.Bt_name
HAVING COUNT(L.Bc_id) >1;
```

Is it the joins which are causing `COUNT(L.Bc_id)` to be >1 for all records where `L.Date_back` Is NULL? FYI only one should be returned (deliberate input error).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are inadvertently creating a Cartesian product between `Book_Title` and `Loan`.

Try this:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BC.Bt_id) > 1
```

Comment: hi,

MS Access 2007 returns SYNTAX ERROR (MISSING OPERATOR) with that change. Have tried UNIQUE also and same error message. Guess this could be my issue, sadly I must use these products.

Comment: In the future it would help if you mention in your question what technology you're using.

Comment: For the Access Database Engine, you have to do the DISTINCT part in a subquery :(

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with the brackets? Why not this?

```
SELECT BT.Bt_Name, count(*) ct FROM Book_Title BT

INNER JOIN  Book_Copy BC on BT.Bt_id = BC.Bt_id

INNER JOIN Loan L ON BC.Bc_id = L.Bc_id

WHERE L.Date_back Is NULL

GROUP BY BT.Bt_name HAVING COUNT(*) >1;
```

Or do I have the wrong end of the stick?